# Proper mmap use - Python

Tags: python, mmap

I'm trying to use **mmap** to load a dictionary from file. 
I'll explain my problem on simplified example. In real, I have 10 files, which have to be loaded in miliseconds (or act like been loaded).

So lets have a dictionary - **50 mb**. My program should find a value by key under 1 sec. Searching in this dictionary is not a problem, it could be done far under 1 sec. The problem is that when sb puts an input into the text field and press enter, the program starts to load the dictionary into memory so program can find a key. This loading can takes several seconds but I have to get result under **1 sec** (dictionary can't be loaded before pressing enter). So I was recommended to use mmap module which should be far faster.

I can't google a good example. I've tried this (I know that it is an incorrect use)

```
def loadDict():
    with open('dict','r+b') as f: # used pickle to save
        fmap = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0)
        dictionary = cpickle.load(fmap)
    return dictionary


def search(pattern):
    dictionary = loadDict()
    return dictionary['pattern']
```

> > > search('apple') <- it still takes many seconds

Could you give me a good example of proper mmap use?

Comment: Why do you assume that mmap is faster than normal file IO functions?

Comment: @Kay Because I was told (in my university), that mmap loads only that part of a file which is needed in certain moment so it doesn't needs to load a whole file into the memory which takes many secs. And that's the reason why I should use mmap.

Comment: The purpose of `mmap` is to [map a file into memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) and implement *demand paging*. This means a particular segment will only be read from disk into memory the first time you access it (but then stays in memory). That means that **repeatedly** accessing the same chunks of a file and seeking forth and back in the file will be very fast. But since for your purpose you basically need random access to the entire file, using `mmap` is obviously not going to help here, but instead make things worse.

Comment: *"dictionary can't be loaded before pressing enter"* - why?

Comment: Maybe a sqlite database instead of pickling would be an option?

Comment: @user3371056 Added the answer, but realized we need more context on the dictionary you're trying to load.

Answer (score 6):

Using an example file of 2,400,000 keys/values (52.7 megabytes) pairs such as:

```
key1,value1
key2,value2
etc , etc
```

Creating example file:

```
with open("stacktest.txt", "a") as f: 
    contents = ["key" + str(i) + ",value" + str(i) for i in range(2400000)]
    f.write("\n".join(contents) + "\n")
```

What is actually slow is having to construct the dictionary. Reading a file of 50mb is fast enough. Finding a value in a wall of text of this size is also fast enough. Using that, you will be able to find a single value in under 1 second.

Since I know the structure of my file I am able to use this shortcut. This should be tuned to your exact file structure though:

Reading in the file and manually searching for the known pattern (searching for the unique string in the whole file, then using the comma delimiter and newline delimiters).

```
with open("stacktest.txt") as f: 
    bigfile = f.read()
    my_key = "key2399999"
    start = bigfile.find(my_key)
    comma = bigfile[start:start+1000].find(",") + 1
    end = bigfile[start:start+1000].find("\n")
    print bigfile[start+comma:start+end]
    # value2399999
```

Timing for it all: **0.43s** on average

Mission accomplished?