# Best way to load a mmap dictionary in Python without deserializing

Tags: python, mmap, rocksdb, data-serialization

Context:

I've got Python processes running on the same container and I want to be able to share a read-only key-value object between them.

I'm aware I could use something like Redis to share that info, but I'm looking for optimal solution in regards to latency as well as memory usage.

My idea was to generate a binary object on disk and open that file using [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html)

Question:
That brings me to my question, is there a binary format or library that would load a read-only file in ram an offer a dictionary interface, without the need to deserialize the file content? This way I could mmap the file in every process, all process would be re-using the same RAM for that file and I would be able to access the file's content with a dict-like interface?

I'm looking a file/object format for dictionaries, similar to what Parquet is to columnar storage, that could be consumed in read-only mode by python.

Comment: If it's read-only, why not just read once into a `dict` before forking to all processes in a way that they will have access to the referenced `dict`? Really though your approach has certain issues, [please refer to comments attached to the question of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449645/proper-mmap-use-python).

Comment: @metatoaster.  This will work on Unix, but not on Mac.  Unix uses fork() to create new processes, but Mac creates a new process.

Comment: @FrankYellin OP didn't specify Mac, though if OP really do want to share the same memory across process they might also want to consider [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) instead.

Comment: Good idea @metatoaster. What limits me right now is that my processes are launched by gunicorn, so unless I fork the code and can’t the logic there. Also I mentioned the data would be immutable, but I was thinking a loading a new file every hour with the most up to date info.

Comment: Well, if `gunicorn` is already being used to launch _new_ Python processes, [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240278/sharing-memory-in-gunicorn) (and all the linked threads on the side-bar) may be more relevant - you may consider having a dedicated process that will provide the data, but that's kind of replicating redis...

Comment: I tried to clarify the question. I'm really looking for a binary file/object storage for dictionaries/Map  with a python interface.

Comment: you should use a sqlite file  instead and connect to it using a regular sql client from all processes

Comment: If I understand you suggesting @AsadAwadia, you are suggesting to load the sqlite DB using https://www.sqlite.org/mmap.html to get RAM speed with no disk access ?

Comment: No. I am saying you don't need mmap at all. Just use sqlite and it will be more than sufficient for your needs. If it is not then ping me again and we can go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is read-only, and you do not need to iterate over keys in lexicographic order: [use constant database cdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdb_(software)). They are bindings for python.
You might want to look into an easy grab in the stdlib called [`dbm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#module-dbm).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. 
I looked at flatbuffers + capnproto and they didn't really support well associative array

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the file is small - in every process slurp it into memory

Else use sqlite

> My idea was to generate a binary object on disk and open that file using mmap

You should not be using mmap

Comment: My file is pretty big. Let's say half the instance RAM. Loading it in ram in every process is not an option. sqllite could be an option

Comment: How big is the file? And how big is the instance? And how many processes?

Comment: I'm trying to get as many process running as I can, right now 4G of ram per instance running 8 processes. The file is around 2GB